# Getting the password expire time

Tags: rhel, password, non-root-user

Let me preface this with: I do **NOT** have root access available.

I recently got locked out of my account because I did not know the password expiration was getting close, then elapsed. I want to add a check to my startup script that checks and displays the time so I know when it is coming near.

Is there a command or way of getting the timestamp when my user password will expire?

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to get that information from the `chage` utility. Doesn't require root to run in list mode.

Note: this most likely only works for local, `passwd`-based authentication. I don't know if it can be made to work with authentication modes that don't put login information in the `passwd`/`shadow` files. I'm guessing these solutions provide their own tools, but don't know about them.

```
$ chage -l test                       
Last password change                                : Apr 17, 2012
Password expires                                    : Apr 27, 2012
Password inactive                                   : never
Account expires                                     : May 20, 2012
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 10
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

I've used that with a quick awk to display my password expiration date on login.

Comment: Odd, I get an error: unknown user. I even tried `whoami | xargs chage -l` to make sure I wasn't doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: What does whoami return, and what does `grep $(whoami) /etc/password` do?

Comment: This appears to only work if the user is local (not in LDAP or other database).

Comment: @Patrick: you're most likely right, and I don't have access to machines with that type of authentication setup. So can't provide additional info.

Comment: `whoami` does return my proper username, but I do believe the system is using LDAP.

Answer (score 4):

In ldap you will do something like:

```
ldapsearch -x -Z  uid=$1 pwdChangedTime | \
          grep -vE '^#|^$' | grep pwdChangedTime | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

From `chage` you can do multiple changes and can know the login details as follows...

```
Usage: chage [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -d, --lastday LAST_DAY        set date of last password change to LAST_DAY
  -E, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -I, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -l, --list                    show account aging information
  -m, --mindays MIN_DAYS        set minimum number of days before password
                                change to MIN_DAYS
  -M, --maxdays MAX_DAYS        set maximim number of days before password
                                change to MAX_DAYS
  -W, --warndays WARN_DAYS      set expiration warning days to WARN_DAYS
```

and if you have Root access then can change your password expire time just edit ..

```
vim /etc/login.defs
```

just setup the vlaues below...

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS 30
PASS_MIN_DAYS 1
PASS_WARN_AGE 7
```

It may help you