# Last Password Change of A User

Tags: password, accounts

I'm am currently trying to figure out a command that will show the last password change of a user on a UNIX system.

I have tried running the command passwd -Sa and it gives the password change date formatted in 00/00/0000. However I want to only list the date of the last user from that command. I have tried piping the command to grep, but I can't seem to get my syntax correct.

I'm looking for just the date output as the result of this command.

Current command attempted:

```
grep $USER | passwd -Sa
```

Any help on my errors is appreciated!

Comment: This varies a lot between Unix variants. Which Unix variant are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Giving more information gets better answers.  Offhand, on OpenSUSE, I see that

```
passwd -S -a
```

gives a record for each entry in `/etc/passwd`, like this:

```
thomas PS 03/01/2013 0 99999 7 -1
```

so you could filter that with awk:

```
passwd -S -a | awk -v user=$USER '{ if ( $1 == user ) { printf  "%s\n",  $3; } }'
```

However, the `passwd` command wants to do this as `root`, so your script would have to do something more elegant than using the `$USER` variable (that's for the **current** user).  The reason it wants `root` is that it is reading the contents of `/etc/shadow`, which is not public.

You could use [`chage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chage.1.html), which shows a different report — but in a quick check, it prompts for the user's password (which probably is not what you want):

> The `chage` program requires a shadow password file to be available.
>
> The `chage` command is restricted to the ***root*** user, except for the `-l`
>   option, which may be used by an unprivileged user to determine when
>   his/her password or account is due to expire.

Further reading:

- [passwd - change user password](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html), showing options `-S` and `-a`
- [shadow - shadowed password file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html), holding date of last password change
- [Getting the password expire time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36695/getting-the-password-expire-time), shows `chage`, but omits the password prompt...

Comment: Great read, and excellent help, solved my issue nicely.

Sometimes it's just easier when someone is able to make sense of the man pages. Just a quick question too, is there a way of reading passwd as anything other than root, or will passwd only read with root access?

Comment: It's only as root because it is reading the contents of `/etc/shadow` (which is readable only by root).  I seem to recall a different way for current user, may update the answer to note that...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework exercise, so:

- `sort` can sort input numerically, and can sort by multiple defined columns if necessary.
- `cut` can print a subset of the input columns, using a set of characters to define column separators.
- `a | b` sends the output of command `a` to command `b`.
- `head` and `tail` return the first and last lines of a file, respectively.
- You generally can't inquire about other users without being root (that is, using `sudo`). You can avoid that (and any `grep`ping) by simply using `passwd --status` to get the status of the *current* user.
- If you want to [make sure that users change their password regularly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I'm sure there are already finished solutions out there, since Linux distros have had this functionality for many years.

Comment: It's not a homework, this is part of a openSUSE server that I'm currently configuring. I'm having a list of commands neatly formatted that show for each user on the system as they login, the last password change I just can't figure out and sort properly.

Comment: @Mister123 well your first problem is that your `grep $USER | passwd -Sa` is backwards. `passwd -Sa | grep $USER` is at least the right way around: `passwd -Sa` outputs some data and `grep $USER` selects what concerns `$USER` from that data.